# Question concerning an application of Cauchy-Schwarz

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Specifically, the question is as follows:

> Prove that for every integrable real-valued $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$,
>   $$\left(\int_1^ef(x)dx\right)^2\leq\int_1^ex(f(x))^2dx.$$

I'm really just looking for assistance getting started on this problem. It is homework, so I request hints, not a full solution. For reference, this was asked in the context of linear algebra, not real analysis.

I am able to show that
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\int_1^ef(t)g(t)dt$$
is an inner product on $L^2$. We have developed the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but not Schwarz's inequality, so this question is presumably solvable simply using
$$|\langle u,v\rangle|\leq\|u\|\|v\|$$
(where $u$ and $v$ are elements of some vector space). So, setting $g=1$, we have
$$\left(\int_1^ef(x)dx\right)^2=|\langle f,g\rangle|^2\leq(\|f\|\|1\|)^2=(e-1)\int_1^e(f(x))^2dx.$$
But I don't see how to draw the desired conclusion from here (so maybe I'm not approaching it right??).

Comment: What happens if $u = f(x)/\sqrt x$ and $g = \sqrt x$?

Comment: @JavaMan You mean $v=\sqrt{x}$?

Comment: @JavaMan Something like $\left(\int_1^ef\right)^2=\left|\int_1^ef\right|^2=|\langle u,v\rangle|^2\leq(\|u\|\|v\|)^2=\left(\sqrt{\int_1^e\frac{f^2}{x}}\sqrt{\int_1^ex}\right)^2=\int_1^e\frac{f^2}{x}\int_1^ex\leq\int_1^exf^2$

Comment: Oops. I meant $u = f(x) \sqrt x$ and $v =1/ \sqrt x$

Comment: I don't think your last inequality in your most recent comment is valid...

Comment: @JavaMan You're correct. I've applied that idea to the hint posted below and it works out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
\begin{align}
\int^e_1 \frac{dx}{x}  = 1.
\end{align}

Comment: Ah. This is a better formulation of the idea presented in the comments. Thank you.

Comment: @Atsina Basically the same thing.

Comment: @xbh Indeed. It's just (slightly) easier to work with.